# Redirect www and http requests to https://, catching all domains, in nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx, configuration, no-www

In nginx, we wish to redirect all requests sent to:

```
https://www.<domain>
http://www.<domain>
http://<domain>
```

To:

```
https://<domain>
```

ie SSL, without the www prefix, as a catch-all, without specifying each domain individually.

The config we have come up with *nearly* works:

```
server {
        server_name "~^www\.(.*)$" ;
        return 301 https://$1$request_uri ;
}

server {
        listen                  80 default;
        client_max_body_size    10m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        return                  301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen                  443;
        ssl                     on;
        ..... etc ......
```

...but the first server block (the www catch) seems to be matching all requests, and not just the ones that are www.*

Answer (score 2):

[nginx manual: A redirect to a main site](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html)

```
server {
    listen   80;
    listen   [::]:80;

    server_name www.example.com;

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen   443 default_server ssl;

    server_name www.example.com example.org;

    ssl_certificate        /path/to/my/cert;
    ssl_certificate_key  /path/to/my/key;
}
```

don't lose “everything else”:

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    return       301 http://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

more efficient, by only running the rewrite on the http protocol it avoids having to check the $scheme variable on every request ([IfIsEvil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil))

Maybe you can try use in one place 80/443:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    listen   [::]:80;
    listen   443 default ssl;

    server_name www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate        /path/to/my/cert;
    ssl_certificate_key  /path/to/my/key;

    if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
       rewrite ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Valeriy. Do you know how to apply this to catch all domains?

Comment: the empty server is actually the catch all server

Comment: @ValeriySolovyov why that `if` condition in the last snippet?

Comment: @Mohammad AbuShady  if it's not https -> redirect. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html $ssl_protocol — returns the protocol of an established SSL connection;

Comment: well, i would try to avoid `if`s, the first solution seems better to me, 3 server blocks and nginx will match to the correct one.
http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil

Comment: Doesn't this run into the problem that both `https://www.example.com` and  `https://example.com` are supported, contrary to what the OP needs?